# Google Map v2 in view not in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to use google maps v2 in view. Not in fragment. 
All examples are implemented using fragments. 
I want to use map in small part of the page dynamically.

**I have multiple pages in a activity, I want to create mapView's dynamically.**

Is it possible to create mapView's dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use map in small part of the page.

This does not prevent you from using `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment`. That being said, you can use `MapView` directly, as is covered in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview).

Comment: Why do you think he will still need MapFragment/SupportMapFragment? I think MapView can be used just like any other view. I once started this way. But routing through the lifecycle events of the containing activity into the view is a bit unhandy. So I ended up in using SupportMapFragment instead. But it also worked without.

Comment: @user2808624: "Why do you think he will still need MapFragment/SupportMapFragment?" -- I did not say that he *needed* those. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: Ah I see what you meant: Even a small part could be realized with MapFragment. I am no native English speaker. So i misunderstood "prevent" in the meaning of "this does not save you from".

Comment: I updated the question. I can use MapView object but I want to create MapView dynamically because I have multiple page in a activity. When user see the page map must load.

Comment: @ak_: AFAIK, you are welcome to call `new MapView()` with appropriate constructor parameters, just like with any other widget.